# Allocate clinicians to patients based on whether they are free

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with patient.time.in and patient.time.out which indicates when they are due to see a clinician and how long they will be take. There are 4 clinicians available: c("Ian", "Dan", "Anita")

```
patient.time.in <- 
        c("09:00:00","09:03:00",
          "09:30:00","09:38:00",
          "10:00:00","10:30:00",
          "11:00:00","11:05:00",
          "12:00:00","12:30:00",
          "14:30:00","15:30:00")

patient.date.in <- "2022/03/29"



appointment.length <- c(runif(n=NROW(patient.time.in),min=10,max=90))

patient.infection <- sample(c("C","P","NA"),replace = TRUE,prob = c(1/2,1/3,1-1/2+1/3),size = NROW(patient.time.in))# c("P","P","NA","P","C","NA","C","P","NA","NA","C","P")

patient.roster <- data.frame(
                          ID=seq(1:12),
                          patient.time.in=lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(patient.date.in,patient.time.in)),
                          patient.time.out=lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(patient.date.in,patient.time.in))+lubridate::minutes(round(appointment.length)),
                          patient.infection=patient.infection,
                          seen.yet=rep("No"),
                          binary.seen.yet=0,
                          room=0)
```

How can I allocate the clinicians based on whether they are free?

So far I have:

```
patient.roster %>%
mutate(clinician = case_when(patient.time.in > lag(patient.time.out,1)~ "Ian",
                           TRUE~"Dan")) %>%
mutate(clinician = case_when(row_number()!=1 & clinician=="Ian" & patient.time.in > lag(patient.time.out,1)~ "Dan",
                           TRUE~"Anita")) %>%
                           select(patient.time.in, patient.time.out, clinician)
```

Expected Output: Coincidentally they are Ian Dan Anita repeated.

```
 patient.time.in     patient.time.out    clinician
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>    
 1 2022-03-29 09:00:00 2022-03-29 10:02:00 Ian    
 2 2022-03-29 09:03:00 2022-03-29 10:21:00 Dan    
 3 2022-03-29 09:30:00 2022-03-29 10:53:00 Anita    
 4 2022-03-29 09:38:00 2022-03-29 10:45:00 Ian    
 5 2022-03-29 10:00:00 2022-03-29 11:06:00 Dan    
 6 2022-03-29 10:30:00 2022-03-29 11:34:00 Anita    
 7 2022-03-29 11:00:00 2022-03-29 12:27:00 Ian    
 8 2022-03-29 11:05:00 2022-03-29 12:21:00 Dan    
 9 2022-03-29 12:00:00 2022-03-29 12:18:00 Anita    
10 2022-03-29 12:30:00 2022-03-29 13:28:00 Ian
```

Comment: Can you use `set.seed` as some of data points you generated are with random values

Comment: In your expected result, Dan still has patient 2 in the room when patient 5 goes into the room. Is this really the expected result? Your described algorithm cannot be done with the supplied data, since you have 4 patients in rooms between 10:00 and 10:21  but only 3 clinicians.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for looking at this so quickly! They have separate rooms. I’m thinking that they will be allocated to Ian even if they have to wait until he is free as theatrically he’s the next one free. Maybe it’s not the best though?

Comment: @HCAI but then does the patient's time not have to be extended to take account for the late start? And then that affects Dan's availability later, which has to be taken into account for subsequent patients' allocations? It seems there are too many what-ifs and edge cases. Particularly if this is for actual rostering. What would happen if a patient doesn't show up, or shows up early when a clinician is free, or a session doesn't run to time, or a clinician is off sick, etc. etc?

Comment: Yes, you’re right. It is deceptively complex. To include all of that would you still use case_when or would you do it in a big if else statement?